# Sparse Matrices Storage formats - Conversion

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix

Is there an efficient way of converting a sparse matrix in Compressed Row Storage(CRS) format to Coordinate List (COO) format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Yousef Saad's library [SPARSKIT](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/SPARSKIT/) -- he has subroutines to convert back and forth between compressed sparse row and coordinate formats, as well as several other sparse matrix storage schemes.

Anyhow, to see how to get the coordinate format from the compressed one, it's easiest to consider how you could have come up with the compressed row format in the first place. Say you have a sparse matrix in COO, where you've put everything in order, for example

```
rows: 1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3 ...
cols: 1  3  5  9  2  3  7  9  11 1  2  3 ...
```

So the non-zero entries in row 1 are (1,1), (1,3), (1,5), (1,9) and so forth. You're storing a lot of redundant data in the array of rows; you can instead just have an array `ia` such that `ia(i)` tells you the starting address in the array `cols` for row `i`. In our example above, we would then have

```
ia  : 1  5  10  ...
cols: 1  3  5  9  2  3  7  9  11 1  2  3 ...
```

To go from COO to CSR, we just use the fact that

```
ia(i+1) = ia(i) + number of non-zero entries in row i
```

for any i. Knowing that, you can work backwards to get the COO format from CSR.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for this, I worked out a similar solution yesterday. I used the fact that values are sorted by row in CSR and also that we already know the number of Non-Zeroes in every row. I used a counter that is incremented up to the number of non-zeroes in every row and then resets. At this point, row_number is incremented by 1. And the whole thing repeats itself for every row. This is way we have the (row,col,val) for every element in the matrix and we can build the COO format in linear time.